# Passing Parameters (Novice) (Java)

Tags: java, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

I'm fairly beginner when it comes to Java, as I've focused more on Js for University rather than the OOP-heavy brother of it and as a result, I can't quite pass my parameters properly.

I'm looking to generate a random number in 'generateMonsterCode' and pass it into 'chooseMonster', but I can't quite grasp how to accomplish this.

```
/**
 * Randomnly choose a type of monster of varying hp/mp/loot drops
 * @return rndGen
 */
public int generateMonsterCode (){
    Random rndGens = new Random();
    int rndGen = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
       rndGen = rndGens.nextInt(4) + 1;
    }

    return rndGen;
}

/**
 * Define which monster is chosen
 */
public void chooseMonster(){

    switch(rndGen){
        case 1: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
        case 2: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
        case 3: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
        case 4: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
    }     
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

**Updated regarding feedback**

```
    /**
 * Randomnly choose a type of monster of varying hp/mp/loot drops
 * @return rndGen
 */

public void generateMonsterCode (){
Random rndGens = new Random();
    int rndGen = 0;

    rndGen = rndGens.nextInt(4) + 1;

    chooseMonster(rndGen);

}

/**
 * Define which monster is chosen
 */

private void chooseMonster(int rndGen){

    switch(rndGen){
    case 1: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
            break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
            break;
    case 3: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
            break;
    case 4: System.out.println("Monster:" + rndGen);
            break;
    }

}
```

Would this perhaps be better code practice?

Comment: `public void chooseMonster(int rndGen)`

Comment: Java and Javascript are not brothers (or sisters). More like inlaws, forced into a political marriage.

Comment: [Parameters in Java](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/) **OR** [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but that for loop in `generateMonsterCode` is pointless and the same as just `return rndGens.nextInt(4) + 1`.

Comment: Well, it works now, right? Without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish, I can't tell you 100% that you're following every best practice, but there's nothing about what you have here that alarms me. Looks good :)

Comment: Does that answer your question, or were you looking for something more concrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are specified by placing them in the parentheses beside the method declaration.

`public void chooseMonster()` is a method that takes no parameters.

`public void chooseMonster(int i){` takes an int as a parameter and names it `i` in the scope of the method.

When you specify a parameter for a method, you then must pass a variable of the type specified when calling it. So, in `generateMonsterCode()`, after you generate the random number, you'll simply call `chooseMonster(rndgen)`.

Within that method, you can refer to the `int` you passed into it with:

`i.doSomething()`;

Does this Make sense? Let me know if I can explain any of this more carefully: I'm brushing against some of the fundamental aspects of object-oriented programming here, and it's important that you grasp these concepts if you want to have a role in the future.

FYI: On the other end of the method declaration is the return type - in your case, it's void, meaning that nothing is returned. An alternative way of structuring this would be to have your `generateMonsterCode()` method return an int:

```
public int generateMonsterCode(){ 
    .... generate random number
    return rdngen();
```

and call it at the beginning of your `chooseMonster()` method.

```
public void chooseMonster() {
      int i = generateMonsterCode();
      ... do work
}
```

Note that this is not necessarily better or worse than doing it the other way, I'm just mentioning it for purposes of explanation.

Also FYI: @supericy is right about the for loop you're using in your random generation. And you should also probably examine what the `public` access modifier does and whether you really need it (you probably don't) - but these issues are outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I've made a few changes in the OP and removed the loop. I now see the needlessness of the loop.